# Retrieve XMl Xpath with namespace

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML with namespace as following.

```
 <WDA.Application.Configuration xmlns="WDA.Application.Configuration">
      <Portals>
        <Portal PortalID="jhgjuhu6yu8678" Type="default" />
      </Portals>
    </WDA.Application.Configuration>
```

How can i extract the x path and call **SelectSingleNode**(**xpath**).I came to know about registering Namespaces,But how do i do it and use it exactly is not clear.Can anyone please help me :)

Comment: what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: I want to change the value of PortalId and for that i need to retrieve its XPATH.But because of xml namespace,i am not able to get the node.Please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured out the xpath yet since I'm not familiar with multiple namespaces, but why not use powershell xml-parser?

```
$xml = [xml](Get-content c:\myfile.xml)

#GetElementsByTagName(tagname, namespace)
$xml.GetElementsByTagName("WDA.Application.Configuration", "WDA.Application.Configuration") | 
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Portals.Portal.PortalID = "testvalueforportalid"
    }

$xml.Save("c:\myfile.xml")
```

**UPDATE** To use namespaces in xpath, you need to register it first in a namespacemanager. Sample:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\test.xml)
$ns = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$ns.AddNamespace("ns1", "WDA.Application.Configuration")
$xml.SelectSingleNode('//ns1:WDA.Application.Configuration', $ns)


xmlns                                             Portals                                          
-----                                             -------                                          
WDA.Application.Configuration                     Portals
```

Comment: Actually there are multiple nodes like his which i want to edit.So i don't want to keep it specific to this code rather i want to use x path to reach the nodes.

Comment: see update for xpath solution. If there are multiple nodes, you can filter using `where` ( `?` ) and foreach too. xpath isn't the only way in PowerShell =)

Answer (score 0):

Note that attributes are typically not namespace qualified.  In this case you don't need to mess with namespaces *if* there is only a single PortalID you're looking for e.g.:

```
 $xml = [xml]@'
 <WDA.Application.Configuration xmlns="WDA.Application.Configuration">
      <Portals>
        <Portal PortalID="jhgjuhu6yu8678" Type="default" />
      </Portals>
    </WDA.Application.Configuration>
'@

$xml | Select-Xml -XPath '//@PortalID' | Foreach {$_.Node.'#text' = 'abcd'}
$xml | Format-Xml
```

Outputs:

```
<WDA.Application.Configuration xmlns="WDA.Application.Configuration">
  <Portals>
    <Portal PortalID="abcd" Type="default" />
  </Portals>
</WDA.Application.Configuration>
```

Note that `Format-Xml` is a [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) cmdlet.

If you need to use namespaces to filter on a particular element then you can put those in a hashtable and pass into `Select-Xml` like so:

```
... | Select-Xml -XPath '//dns:Portal' -Namespace @{dns='WDA.Application.Configuration'}
```